# How to list files in Blob azure using spark R

Tags: r, apache-spark, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using SparkR on Rstudio server with HDi cluster based on Azure blob storage. I am trying to list the files contained in a Blob container.
I tried: `list.files(pattern = ".*.csv")` as we do in R but it doesn't show us anything and i got an error.

Does anyone know how to list files in a Blob container from R ?

Comment: how did you do that ? SparkR on AzureBlob

Comment: I use RStudio Server on Azure

Answer (score 0):

There is a recursive flag in the list files function

```
files <- list.files(path = "parent-folder", pattern = "\\.csv$", recursive = TRUE)
```

It's probably safer to set the `path` parameter in case the script runs in `/` or something else (Sometimes R studio runs scripts in unexpected paths).

Comment: Does it also work with sparkR on rstudio server on an azure cluster deployed on a blob storage ?

Comment: I tested with R studio. It should be universal across platforms. Clustered machines will need a shared file system to work correctly.

Comment: We tried it, and sadly it doesn't work with Rstudio on a HDI cluster deployed with a blob as storage.